# Find page break in Word using OPEN XML

Tags: c#-4.0, openxml, openxml-sdk

How do i find page breaks in my word document using open xml? I checked the document.xml 
there is no reference of:

1. w:br
2. w:lastrenderedpagebreak

How do i know if there is a page break is inserted ?

Comment: you will find it only if you have page breaks in you document. But if your document is floating to next pages with out any page breaks, then that will not have these tags

Answer (score 3):

Figured out there is another way a page break gets added to the word document .

That is using the sectPr tag the page size property .

If the content size increases then the exceeding content is pushed to the next page .

[image]

Comment: How do you calculate the content size? and what do you compare it with?